# mysql workbench password not storing

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a new database using MySQL Workbench and cannot save a password using the "Store in Keychain" button. I have looked everywhere and no answers have been straightforward. I am trying to access the server using

```
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost", "root", "password");
```

so, I need a password. I tried accessing it without a password, but that did not work. When I open the Workbench and click the "Store in Keychain" button next to Password and enter the password, I follow that up by testing the connection and entering the password. No matter what I do, the password never works. I try clearing it, which then allows me to access it without a password, but that is no good to me. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Look - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: i tried that. when i do it i get: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PRIVILEGED
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password')' at line 1

Comment: I am using a mac, if that makes any difference?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Double click on the connection, supply the password to login.  Choose Server -> editor/management screen, then go into "Users and privileges", highlight the account and change the password there.